# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - React image error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

```
class SingleProduct extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      edit: false,
      name: "",
      imageUrl: null,
      price: 0,
      description: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onImageChange = this.onImageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  onImageChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let image = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(image.src);
      this.setState({
        imageUrl: URL.createObjectURL(image),
      });
    }
  };

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props.cocktail);
    this.props.updateCocktail({ ...this.props.cocktail, ...this.state });
    this.setState({
      edit: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { cocktail, isAdmin } = this.props;
    const { edit, name, price, description, imageUrl } = this.state;
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, onImageChange } = this;

    return (
      <div>
        {isAdmin && (
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              this.setState((prevState) => ({ edit: !prevState.edit }))
            }
          >
            Edit Cocktail
          </button>
        )}

        {edit ? (
          <form>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={name}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Upload Image:
              <input type="file" name="imageUrl" onChange={onImageChange} />
              <img src={imageUrl} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Description:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="description"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={description}
              />
            </label>
            <label>
              Price:
              <input
                type="text"
                name="price"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={price}
              />
            </label>
            <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        ) : (.....stuff)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am attempting to a "file" button in my form and it does allow me to successfully add image and it displays that change in the backend. However, once I reload the page, I am thrown this error "GET blob:http://localhost:3000/3f9fwf19-c526-4404-bb-20a433542ed net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" and the image doesn't render.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?